# Copying formula from cell below to newly inserted cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into a problem when I try to copy the formula from a cell into a newly inserted cell directly above it.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Rows(RowValue).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
Cells(RowValue, 10).Resize(2, 1).Formula = Cells(RowValue + 1, 10).Formula
```

Lets say that cell `I7` used to have the code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A7="","",INDEX(Table_TipData14[NC_STATUS],MATCH('Rack Report'!A7,Table_TipData14[SN],0))),"")
```

---

But after line one of my VBA code, that cell will become `I8` and the code inside it will automatically change to:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A8="","",INDEX(Table_TipData14[NC_STATUS],MATCH('Rack Report'!A8,Table_TipData14[SN],0))),"")
```

---

Which is good, that is what I want to happen after that line of VBA code.

The problem is, when the second line of VBA code runs. It makes cell `I7` what cell `I8` should be and makes cell `I8` what cell `I9` should be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Copy Formula from Below or Above

Your code does exactly what it is supposed to do, but not what you desire.

### Simplified Example of Current Code

For `rowvalue = 7`

Cell `J6` contains `=A6`
Cell `J7` contains `=A7`
Cell `J8` contains `=A8`

When you insert the row, Cell `J6` stays the same, cell `J7` is empty, previous cell `J7` moved a row below (`J8`) and contains `=A8` and previous cell `J8` moved a row below (`J9`) and contains `=A9`.

Now when you apply `.Resize(2)` the range will be `J7:J8` (Inserted empty cell and previous `J7` cell, now `J8` cell). Now you take the formula of `J8` which is `=A8` and write it to `J7` and it stays `=A8` and the formula in the next row (`J8`) becomes `=A9`, which is not what you intended.

### Solution 1

You can **`Copy`** the **cell** from the row below, which will copy the formula.

```
Sub CopyCell1()
    Const rowvalue As Long = 7
    Rows(rowvalue).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    Cells(rowvalue + 1, 10).Copy Destination:=Cells(rowvalue, 10)
    ' Or simply:
    'Cells(rowvalue + 1, 10).Copy Cells(rowvalue, 10)
End Sub
```

### Solution 2

If you insist on using **`Resize`**, you have to add an `Offset` to the previous cell (cell above) and then 'apply' `Resize` and write the formula from the cell above (e.g. `J6`) starting from the cell above (e.g. `=A6`).

```
Sub CopyCell2()
    Const rowvalue As Long = 7
    Rows(rowvalue).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    Cells(rowvalue, 10).Offset(-1).Resize(2).Formula _
            = Cells(rowvalue - 1, 10).Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand what it was I was typing in!  I just copy and pasted from a different Q/A and wasn't getting what i wanted and wasn't sure why.  Solution 1 did the trick!  Thank you.